# За сколько выполнилось консольное приложение C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Можно ли как то посмотреть за сколько выполнилось консольное приложение ?

Comment: засеки при помощи stopwatch. Запринть на завершении программы значение  стоватча в консоль.

Comment: спасибо, нашел , получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch)

```
Stopwatch sw = new();
sw.Start();

//...код

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Stopwatch.StartNew. и Stop можно не писать :)

Comment: @PashaPash можно :)